# How to configure RabbitMQ to store only part of messages in RAM (because I have really large queue)

Tags: configuration, rabbitmq

I'm going to use RabbitMQ in a project where large amounts of data (~2*10^7 messages, 800 bytes each) need to be stored and processed. Of course, all this data won't fit in RAM, so I have a question: how to configure RabbitMQ to save only part of messages in RAM, and another part -- on disk?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, found answer on my own question, let me share it:

Accordingly to http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/ :

> When queues are small(ish) they will reside entirely within memory. Persistent messages will also get written to disc, but they will only get read again if the broker restarts. But when queues get larger, they will get paged to disc, persistent or not.